# Centring Multiple Nested DIVs Within The Body Tags HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have multiple nested `div's` that follow the flow of the document that contain some content and footer information.  Each `div` has an `id` and the one named `content` is constrained using the `width` `css` property to about `800px`.

The problem I have is that when I expand the webpage, the `div` `content` with all its nested `div's` remains at the top left corner of the webpage with the `30px` `margin`.  I want the `content` `div` and all its nested `div's` to be in the centre of the `div` `main`.  I thought I could achieve this by applying the `css` style `margin 0 auto;`.  I have attached an image to try and illustrate what I mean.  The first image demonstrates the behaviour of my website as it stands.

[image: Div's]

**EDIT:**

Here is my code.  I can provide more if needed:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                margin: 30px;
            }
            #main {
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">

            <div id="main_index">

                <div id="content"></div>
                <div id="footer"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;` Put that on `#main`. This will need a defined height. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/01ajut1j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will only work if the `#content` is smaller than the `#main`, which is basically the screen size.

First make sure that `#main` takes up 100% of the height of the screen by giving the `html`, `body` and `#main` a `height: 100%`.

To position the `#content` in the horizontal and vertical center of the `#main` it will be positioned absolutely. To let it have `#main` as it's frame of reference add `position: relative` to the `#main`. The `#content` gets a `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` which makes the top left of the `#content` start at exactly the center of the `#main`. The `#content` gets a `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to nudge it 50% of its width to the left and 50% of its height to the top. This makes it perfectly centered.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #c66;
  background-color: #f99;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content"">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly how I want it to behave. I do apoligise as looking at my div structure its a bit different to my code above. Give me a few mins and I'll EDIT my original code.  I will also edit my image to match the div's involved.

Comment: Just replace the `#content` in my code with `#main_index` and it should work. Afterwards you can fill the now called `#main_index` with whatever you like, so in you case your `#content` and `#footer`

Comment: Thanks - I've added the code to my css and the main_index div is literally cut in half as in most of my content has disappeared from the top  Also, I am using sublime text 3 and it doesn't seem to recognise transform: translate(-50%, -50%);. Meaning it doesn't auto fill it out like all other css properties.

Comment: Sorry that it doesn't work out. Perhaps try to update the question with more code showing where it goes wrong or add a new question?

Comment: No problem - tbh, I had a good play around with your code and for some reason, all's I needed to do is eradicate the `main` div, and just apply `margin 0 auto` to the `main_index` div.  I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (all Mac) and its behaving the same as your example.  I will mark your answer as correct in this case since you provide some helpful bits of code :-)

Answer (score 0):

the `margin: 0 auto;` wont work unless u give the div a width because if u think about it ,how the browser will calculate the distance from both sides if the div doesn't have a width ?,

u can also align a div in middle with `text-align: center;`, but for the vertical centering there a couple of ways

- u can use the `position: absolute;` trick or use the `vertical-align: middle` but this needs a `display: inline-block;` or it wont work.